# How to use MSBuild Community Tasks in Team Build 2010?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, msbuildcommunitytasks

How to use [MSBuild Community Tasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/) in Team Build 2010? As you know TFS 2010 uses Windows Work Flow instead of Tasks and Target like previous version.

Many Thanks

Comment: I wrote a blog post about my total experience with versioning in Team Build 2010: http://afsharm.blogspot.com/2010/07/versioning-assemblies-with-team-build.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSBuild is still used to build your solution(s)/project(s). The simplest thing would be to install the Community Tasks on your build machine and reference them as you normally would from your solution's project files (*.*proj).

Comment: You are right. But I also have heard that an Activity exists to run custom build tasks. Is it true?

Comment: You could use the MSBuild activity, but in many cases it wouldn't make sense since you would have very little context available to you. When you're manipulating inputs and/or outputs, it's generally better to do it with MSBuild script within one of your project files. For more details, see my blog post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimlamb/archive/2010/06/09/windows-workflow-vs-msbuild-in-tfs-2010.aspx